Can't open Chrome with selenium
When I run the code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.globalacademia.com")

I get the following output from the VisualStudio OUTPUT tab:
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Desktop\testselenium.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.061 seconds

Nothing happens Google Chrome doesn't open!
I am a complete beginner trying to make a Python code that will automatically apply students to many universities - fill application portal fields like diploma, name, surname and etc.
To do this I am learning how to interact with browsers, I am learning with ChatGPT and googling but I am stuck at getting chrome to open in the first place. I have installed Selenium through CMD, installed python through CMD and have installed Visual Studio.
I tried different codes I found online on how to launch Chrome or open some site, none worked and the code I added to this post seemed most up to date from a newer YouTube video.
Advice on how to learn properly is very very welcome I am not techsavvy, but I can keep trying and figure stuff out with the right learning resources. ChatGPT seems to have been a bad idea. First time posting on Stack hope I am doing it right.

You forgot to pass options to your webdriver, just add options=options. Otherwise it won't detach Chrome from your process and will close it immediately after the code is executed. This is an expected behavior which you observe now.

It worked, thank you so much. Do you have any advice on how to improve my learning method. ChatGPT has not been the best teacher but I am also not too keen on doing 0 to 100 tutorials, I like learning as I go. Thanks again. @xoxouser

you can always use input() at the end of code - and it will run script until you press ENTER. It can be useful to add text for this input("Press ENTER to close")

Using a Chrome driver with selenium is greatly simplified in the latest versions. Using selenium 4.21.0 all you need is:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
url = "https://www.globalacademia.com"

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)

Of course, you will need a Chrome browser installed on the platform where you're intending to run your code
